# in Python, get "merge as of" to match multiple (and possibly repetitive) rows of one dataframe to rows of another dataframe based on range of dates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, merge

I have two data frames and I want to merge them based on dates. I want any rows df2 to match with rows of df1 on the condition that the date on df2 entry is within the 5-year-prior window of the date of entry in df1.
to elaborate, let's say df1 looks something like this:

| firm_id | firm_date |
| --- | --- |
| 12345 | 30/11/1994 |
| 12345 | 31/03/1995 |
| 67890 | 31/12/1994 |
| 67890 | 31/03/1995 |

and df2 looks like this:

| firm_id | patent_id | patent_filing_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 14526368 | 15/12/1989 |
| 12345 | 75896328 | 05/06/1994 |
| 12345 | 42589651 | 20/02/1995 |
| 67890 | 54216987 | 20/02/1990 |
| 67890 | 65874139 | 12/07/1993 |
| 67890 | 65874139 | 17/05/1994 |
| 67890 | 58792543 | 13/02/1995 |

The desired output would look like this:

| firm_id | datadate | patent_id | patent_filing_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 30/11/1994 | 14526368 | 15/12/1989 |
| 12345 | 30/11/1994 | 75896328 | 05/06/1994 |
| 12345 | 31/03/1995 | 75896328 | 05/06/1994 |
| 12345 | 31/03/1995 | 42589651 | 20/02/1995 |
| 67890 | 31/12/1994 | 54216987 | 20/02/1990 |
| 67890 | 31/12/1994 | 65874139 | 12/07/1993 |
| 67890 | 31/03/1995 | 65874139 | 12/07/1993 |
| 67890 | 31/03/1995 | 65874139 | 17/05/1994 |
| 67890 | 31/03/1995 | 58792543 | 13/02/1995 |

So as you see, a row from df2 can match with multiple rows of df1 as long its date is within the 5-year-prior window to the date of df1.

so far, I have come up with the following code:

```
df_merge = pd.merge_asof(df2, df1 , left_on='patent_filing_date' , right_on='datadate', 
direction='forward', tolerance=pd.Timedelta(1824, unit="d"), by='firm_id')
```

The problem is, the above code matches each row from df2 to df1 only once and doesn't repeat the rows when necessary. That is, it looks like I am getting the following:

| firm_id | datadate | patent_id | patent_filing_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 30/11/1994 | 14526368 | 15/12/1989 |
| 12345 | 30/11/1994 | 75896328 | 05/06/1994 |
| 67890 | 31/12/1994 | 54216987 | 20/02/1990 |
| 67890 | 31/12/1994 | 65874139 | 12/07/1993 |
| 67890 | 31/03/1995 | 65874139 | 17/05/1994 |
| 67890 | 31/03/1995 | 58792543 | 13/02/1995 |

Whereas, I want each entry from df2 to match with all possible entries from df1 regardless of whether they have matched with another row of df1.

Appreciate any help with *merge as of*, or alternative functions.
Thanks

Comment: for df1, november cant be 31 ( there are only 30 days in november)

Comment: You are correct, my bad.